# Looping through a list of strings in Python sometimes only sees last element of list

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

(ep is a list of strings with a len of 58.)

Calling list on a string is supposed to give a list of the characters. But why in this case did it only see the last string? (Note, unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38444344/python-list-of-dictionaries-only-see-last-element), each element is unique).

```
for s in ep:
    ll = list(s)
ll
['3', '5', '0', ' ', 'U', '.', 'S', '.', ' ', '1', '0', '1', '0']`
```

While in this loop with print() it sees all the elements, but doesn't modify any:

```
for s in ep:
    ll = list(s)
    print(s)
350 U.S. 1
350 U.S. 3
```

Here's another for loop with print that works:

```
for e in ep:
    print([e])
['350 U.S. 1']
['350 U.S. 3']
```

And another without it that only sees the last element:

```
for e in ep:
    ep5 = [e.strip("'").replace(' ', ",")]
ep5
['350,U.S.,1010']
```

And finally:

```
for e in ep:
    ep11 = e.split()
    print(ep11)
['350', 'U.S.', '1']
['350', 'U.S.', '3']
...<snip>...
['350', 'U.S.', '1010']
```

**BUT....**

```
ep11
['350', 'U.S.', '1010']
```

Both a list comprehension and enumerate (omitted) see all the elements, but not the simple for loop, at least not without print(). I know print() adds a newline, but I can't see how that alone accounts for this behavior. Can anyone explain this to me? Python 3.5.2 on Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks.

Comment: You do **not** extend the `ll` list, so all iterations except the previous have no effect in the sense that the result is thrown away.

Comment: Side note, you should really improve your variable names: `ll`, `ep`, `ep11` are all meaningless. `(ep is a list of strings with a len of 58.)` this disclaimer wouldn't be necessary if the variable was just named well.

Answer (score 2):

You're overwriting the same `ll` variable over and over again. Only the last value written will remain.

If you expect the result to be a list of list of string variables, then create a new list and add to it on every iteration:

```
characterLists = []

for s in strings:
    characterLists.append(list(s))

print(characterLists)
```

Better yet, just use a list comprehension:

```
characterLists = [list(s) for s in strings]
print(characterLists)
```

Comment: Wow. As soon as I got up from the computer, it hit me that this might be something like 'seek' in a file object, where you end up at the end of the file and have to reset the cursor. But I don't remember ever hearing that analogy in any tutorial. Anyway, when I came back to add that, I already had 2 responses! It sounds like I need to digest for loops a little more deeply. Let me do that and come back to select an answer later today. Thanks to all!

Comment: There's only a single asnwer (mine) :P